# Panel data regression: Robust standard errors

Tags: r, regression, standard-error, panel-data, robust

my problem is this: I get `NA` where I should get some values in the computation of robust standard errors.

I am trying to do a fixed effect panel regression with cluster-robust standard errors. For this, I follow [Arai (2011)](http://people.su.se/~ma/clustering.pdf) who on p. 3 follows [Stock/ Watson (2006)](https://www.princeton.edu/~mwatson/papers/panelse_5.pdf) (later published in [Econometrica](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/4502057?uid=3737760&uid=2&uid=4&sid=56192307833), for those who have access). I would like to correct the degrees of freedom by `(M/(M-1)*(N-1)/(N-K)`   against downward bias as my number of clusters is finite and I have unbalanced data.

Similar problems have been posted before [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260766/robust-standard-errors-in-ggplot2/9264761#9264761), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389843/clustered-standard-errors-r-panel-data)] on StackOverflow and related problems [[3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28492/understanding-the-plm-package-why-arent-my-standard-errors-correct)] on CrossValidated.

Arai (and the answer in the 1st link) uses the following code for functions (*I provide my data below with some further comment*):

```
gcenter <- function(df1,group) {
    variables <- paste(
        rep("C", ncol(df1)), colnames(df1), sep=".")
    copydf <- df1
    for (i in 1:ncol(df1)) {
        copydf[,i] <- df1[,i] - ave(df1[,i], group,FUN=mean)}
    colnames(copydf) <- variables
    return(cbind(df1,copydf))}

# 1-way adjusting for clusters
clx <- function(fm, dfcw, cluster){
    # R-codes (www.r-project.org) for computing
    # clustered-standard errors. Mahmood Arai, Jan 26, 2008.
    # The arguments of the function are:
    # fitted model, cluster1 and cluster2
    # You need to install libraries `sandwich' and `lmtest'
    # reweighting the var-cov matrix for the within model
    library(sandwich);library(lmtest)
    M <- length(unique(cluster))   
    N <- length(cluster)           
    K <- fm$rank                        
    dfc <- (M/(M-1))*((N-1)/(N-K))  
    uj  <- apply(estfun(fm),2, function(x) tapply(x, cluster, sum));
    vcovCL <- dfc*sandwich(fm, meat=crossprod(uj)/N)*dfcw
    coeftest(fm, vcovCL) }
```

,where the `gcenter` computes deviations from the mean (fixed effect). I then continue and do the regression with `DS_CODE`being my cluster variable (I have named my data 'data').

```
centerdata <- gcenter(data, data$DS_CODE)
datalm <- lm(C.L1.retE1M ~ C.MCAP_SEC + C.Impact_change + C.Mom + C.BM + C.PD + C.CashGen + C.NITA + C.PE + C.PEdummy + factor(DS_CODE), data=centerdata)
M <- length(unique(data$DS_CODE))
dfcw <- datalm$df / (datalm$df - (M-1))
```

and want to calculate

```
clx(datalm, dfcw, data$DS_CODE)
```

However, when I want to compute *uj* (see formula `clx` above) for the variance, I get only at the beginning some values for my regressors, then lots of zeros. If this input *uj* is used for the variance, only `NAs` result.

**My data**

Since my data may be of special structure and I can't figure out the problem, I post the entire thing as a [link](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=58FBD7EAB94B2963!223&authkey=!APTXLzboXcf67Hs) from Hotmail. The reason is that with other data (taken from Arai (2011)) my problem does not occur. Sorry in advance for the mess but I'd be very grateful if you could have a look at it nevertheless. 
The file is a 5mb .txt file containing purely data.

Comment: Arai's paper no longer exist under your link. Can you provide the actual link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time playing around, it works for me and gives me:

```
                         Estimate  Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            4.5099e-16  5.2381e-16  0.8610  0.389254    
C.MCAP_SEC            -5.9769e-07  1.2677e-07 -4.7149 2.425e-06 ***
C.Impact_change       -5.3908e-04  7.5601e-05 -7.1306 1.014e-12 ***
C.Mom                  3.7560e-04  3.3378e-03  0.1125  0.910406    
C.BM                  -1.6438e-04  1.7368e-05 -9.4645 < 2.2e-16 ***
C.PD                   6.2153e-02  3.8766e-02  1.6033  0.108885    
C.CashGen             -2.7876e-04  1.4031e-02 -0.0199  0.984149    
C.NITA                -8.1792e-02  3.2153e-02 -2.5438  0.010969 *  
C.PE                  -6.6170e-06  4.0138e-06 -1.6485  0.099248 .  
C.PEdummy              1.3143e-02  4.8864e-03  2.6897  0.007154 ** 
factor(DS_CODE)130324 -5.2497e-16  5.2683e-16 -0.9965  0.319028    
factor(DS_CODE)130409 -4.0276e-16  5.2384e-16 -0.7689  0.441986    
factor(DS_CODE)130775 -4.4113e-16  5.2424e-16 -0.8415  0.400089  
...
```

This leaves us with the question why it doesn't for you. I guess it has something to do with the format of your data. Is everything numeric? I converted the column classes and it looks like that for me:

```
str(dat)
'data.frame':   48251 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ DS_CODE      : chr  "902172" "902172" "902172" "902172" ...
 $ DNEW         : num  2e+05 2e+05 2e+05 2e+05 2e+05 ...
 $ MCAP_SEC     : num  78122 71421 81907 80010 82462 ...
 $ NITA         : num  0.135 0.135 0.135 0.135 0.135 ...
 $ CashGen      : num  0.198 0.198 0.198 0.198 0.198 ...
 $ BM           : num  0.1074 0.1108 0.097 0.0968 0.0899 ...
 $ PE           : num  57 55.3 63.1 63.2 68 ...
 $ PEdummy      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ L1.retE1M    : num  -0.72492 0.13177 0.00122 0.07214 -0.07332 ...
 $ Mom          : num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PD           : num  5.41e-54 1.51e-66 3.16e-80 2.87e-79 4.39e-89 ...
 $ Impact_change: num  0 -10.59 -10.43 0.7 -6.97 ...
```

What does `str(data)` return for you?

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort and your answer! My `str(data)` returns *Factor* for `DS_CODE` and *int* for `DNEW`. All other results are the same.... BUT: This is the strangest thing: it works now if I use the *reduced* data set (I gave you only the small data set without my other varialbes and the R row numbers). With the big set, I get 1 single row of `NAs` in the computation of *uj*. If I export my entire data set WITHOUT row numbers (`row.names = FALSE`), import it again and do the regression, it works with the big data set. I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

The `plm` package can estimate clustered SEs for panel regressions. The original data is no longer available, so here's an example using dummy data.

```
require(foreign)
require(plm)
require(lmtest)
test <- read.dta("http://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/petersen/htm/papers/se/test_data.dta")

fpm <- plm(y ~ x, test, model='pooling', index=c('firmid', 'year'))

##Arellano clustered by *group* SEs
> coeftest(fpm, vcov=function(x) vcovHC(x, cluster="group", type="HC0"))

t test of coefficients:

            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.029680   0.066939  0.4434   0.6575    
x           1.034833   0.050540 20.4755   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

---

If you're using `lm` models (instead of `plm`), then the `multiwayvcov` package may help.

```
library("lmtest")
library("multiwayvcov")

data(petersen)
m1 <- lm(y ~ x, data = petersen)

> coeftest(m1, vcov=function(x) cluster.vcov(x, petersen[ , c("firmid")], 
   df_correction=FALSE))

t test of coefficients:

            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.029680   0.066939  0.4434   0.6575    
x           1.034833   0.050540 20.4755   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

For more details see:

- [Fama-MacBeth and Cluster-Robust (by Firm and Time) Standard Errors in R](http://landroni.wordpress.com/2012/06/02/fama-macbeth-and-cluster-robust-by-firm-and-time-standard-errors-in-).

See also:

- [Double clustered standard errors for panel data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389843/double-clustered-standard-errors-for-panel-data/11173348#11173348)