# Robust standard errors for clogit regression from survival package in R

Tags: r, stata, logistic-regression, standard-error, robust

I am trying to get robust standard errors for a clogit regression from the survival package in R. In doing so, I am trying to replicate the standard errors reported by the Stata `clogit` command with the `vce(robust)` option.

My formula in R is

```
conditional_logit <- clogit(dependent_variable ~ independent_variable + some_controls + strata(year), method= "exact", data = data_frame)
```

Adding the `robust = TRUE` argument to the function fails with the error:

```
Error in residuals.coxph(fit2, type = "dfbeta", weighted = TRUE) : 
score residuals are not available for the exact method
```

Any attempt to extract robust standard errors via the sandwich or plm packages as suggested [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117052/replicating-statas-robust-option-in-r), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691341/panel-data-regression-robust-standard-errors), [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/exporting-results-of-linear-regression-with-robust-standard-errors/), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367974/different-robust-standard-errors-of-logit-regression-in-stata-and-r) fails with the same error. Similarly, the [clogit function](https://github.com/cran/survival/blob/master/R/clogit.R) includes a condition to stop attempts to calculate robust standard errors when using the `exact` method (line 44). However, conditional_logit$residuals and conditional_logit$score exist in the clogit regression object.

I would be thankful if somebody could help answer the following questions:

- Is it generally impossible or "wrong" to calculate robust standard errors for "exact" conditional logistic regressions? If so, why does Stata allow doing so?
- If not: How could I calculate robust standard errors for clogit regressions in R?
- If it's not possible to calculate robust standard errors based on the data in the clogit regression object: Is there another R package that produces conditional logistic regression models that are equivalent to those produced by the clogit function of the survival package and that include the data that I need to calculate robust standard errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the method of dealing with ties in your original clogit function.

The default for the method command is `method="exact"`. If you use `method="efron"`, for example, then the `robust=TRUE` command works.

Comment: Are you sure this is a correct solution? these two different methods produce different point estimations.

Comment: I'm wondering if you maybe have a solution on how to report the SEs and p-values produced that way in regression tables in stargazer. Have been trying to extract them, because stargazer takes the non-robust SEs.